# MacBook Pro 16" Speakers Spontaneously Making Strange Noise. How do I fix this?

Tags: speakers

I have a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) running MacOS Catalina 10.15.6. Ever since I updated from MacOS Catalina 10.15.5, when I play music on my MacBook speakers, after a few minutes I'll start hearing a horrible distortion noise along with the music. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h07z.jpg for a video I recorded of the problem.

I'm able to temporarily resolve this issue if I plug in my headphones and immediately remove them (as shown in the video), or if I go to *System Preferences* > *Sound* and change the "Alert volume" value. But then after a few minutes, the problem recurs.

I'm getting the impression this is software-based, and it's not clear to me that the upgrade to 10.15.6 is the cause of the issue. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you hear the problem over your headphones?

Comment: I never heard the problem through my headphones.

Comment: Then it’s very *unlikely* software.  Try going into Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting) and see if the problem exists there.

Comment: Interesting. Will try! Why would the problem be fixed once I update "alert volume" then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you report there as well https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251560058?
You are not the only one....
My guess is that it is not the sound card as headphones work fine, but could be a driver / compatibility issue with the speakers. Def looks like a driver/OS not working as expected to me
My issue happened with the exact same version: MacOS Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Thank you for this link! I reset the SMC of my MacBook Pro per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 and the problem seems to have gone away for now!